# Most keyboard shortcuts don't work in Word 2010 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

I can't use <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> in Word 2010 on Windows 8.

Whenever I do, nothing happens. What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The shortcuts for cut, copy and paste are disabled in your Word. To enable the shortcuts again, do this:

1. In Word 2010, press *File » Options*.
2. Open the *Customize Ribbon* tab.
3. Press the *Keyboard shortcuts » Customize* button at the bottom of the left-hand list
4. Select Category *All Commands*
5. Choose respective commands, for example *copy text*
6. Under the section *New shortcut key* enter your desired key (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
7. Save and close the document
8. Restart Word and all of your created shortcuts will work

Answer (score 0):

i just fixed this issue by 
1- In Word 2010, press File » Options.
2- Open the Customize Ribbon tab.
3- Press the Keyboard shortcuts » Customize button at the bottom of the left-hand list
4- Select Category All Commands
5- Choose reset all from the bottom ans save
6- close the file then open it again or open any word file. and try any keyboard shortcut.

Comment: You might clarify and add some screen prints with some arrows or something as your wording could be hard to visual for some readers.